Нестандартный вывод команды `tput sgr0`
У меня несколько VPS-серверов Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS. На всех серверах есть скрипт, содержащий команду: sgr0 > tput.out  (сбрасывает настройки терминала к дефолтным значениям).
Правильный выходной код — ^[[m , который прописывается в файле . Но на одном сервере та же команда почему-то записывает этот код с дополнительными символами: ^[(B ^[[m.
Что может быть причиной вывода этих дополнительных символов?
Может быть, это связано с настройками терминала на данном сервере?  Или же проблема кроется в чём-то другом? Как это исправить?

Предположу что это не выходные коды, а как раз управляющие коды. Эти коды часто состоят из нескольких символов, но все они начинаются с "^[". Это не два символа ^ и [, а представление ASCII-кода ESC (поэтому они и называются escape codes или "эскейп последовательности").

^[[m   -  modesoff SGR0         Turn off character attributes

Чтобы код выполнился можно запустить echo -e \033[m

^[(B    -  setusg0               Set United States G0 character set

Тоже echo -e \033(B
\033 - восмеричный код 27 (ESC) 
Справедливо для VT100 terminal

Спасибо! Но кто эту команду отправляет?

@Mikhail Amk попробуйте сравнить вывод на нормальном и ненормальном сервере echo $TERM  и infocmp |grep sgr*

На сервере где нормально
infocmp |grep sgr*  am, km, mir, msgr, xenl,  setab=\E[4%p1%dm, setaf=\E[3%p1%dm, sgr0=\E[m, smacs=^N, .
На проблемном есть доп строка: infocmp |grep sgr*  am, bce, ccc, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,  sgr=%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m,  sgr0=\E(B\E[m, sitm=\E[3m, smacs=\E(0, smam=\E[?7h, 

$TERM  -
xterm-color     и xterm-256color 
Кажется в этом причина?

@Mikhail Amk разные терминалы - разные результаты.  По этому и tput sgr0 отличаются. Вот ваша разница sgr0=\E[m sgr0=\E(B\E[m

Я знаю  два варианта управления цветом.
Первый:
txtred='\e[0;31m' # Red
txtgrn='\e[0;32m' # Green
txtylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow
txtrst='\e[0m' # reset

вывести anytext зеленым:
$ echo -e  "${txtgrn}anytext${txtrst}"

и такой подход работает на всех серверах правильно.
Второй:
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
RESET=$(tput sgr0)

вывести anytext зеленым:
$ echo -e "${GREEN}anytext${RESET}"

Этот метод тоже работает, но он создаёт проблемы с форматированием текста из-за упомянутого выше.
Хочется понять причину.
